# How to fix, TCP out of range seq number error, when replaying pcap file using scapy and python script?

Tags: python, scapy

I am using following python script to replay PCAP files from Debian machine.

```
from scapy.all import *
global src_ip, dst_ip
src_ip = "10.1.1.14"
dst_ip = "10.1.1.1"
src_mac = "Src_mac_addr"
dst_mac = "Dst_mac_addr"
infile = "mms.pcap"

def my_send(rd, count=100):
    pkt_cnt = 0
    p_out = []

    for p in rd:
        pkt_cnt += 1
        np = p.payload
    if p.haslayer(IP) == 1:
        np[IP].dst = dst_ip
            np[IP].src = src_ip
        del np[IP].chksum
    if p.haslayer(Ether) == 1:
            p[Ether].dst = dst_mac
            p[Ether].src = src_mac
        #del np[IP].chksum
    #del np[TCP].chksum
    if p.haslayer(TCP) == 1:
        del np[TCP].chksum
    if p.haslayer(UDP) == 1:
        del np[UDP].chksum
    #np[IP].show2()
    p_out.append(np)
        if pkt_cnt % count == 0:
            send(PacketList(p_out))
            p_out = []

    # Send remaining in final batch
    send(PacketList(p_out))
    print "Total packets sent %d" % pkt_cnt


try:
    my_reader = PcapReader(infile)
    my_send(my_reader)
except IOError:
    print "Failed reading file %s contents" % infile
    sys.exit(1)
```

But Packets are getting dropped in firewall with the following error messages:

```
 1 11:15:16.481371 no matching TCP flow (#178) TCP: 10.1.1.14 > 10.1.1.1 ports 102 > 1089, SA, MSS 1460, SACK OK, DF, DSCP 0
2 11:15:16.482790 TCP out of range seq number * (#82) TCP: 10.1.1.14 > 10.1.1.1 ports 1089 > 102, A, DF, DSCP 0
3 11:15:16.620475 TCP out of range seq number * (#82) TCP: 10.1.1.14 > 10.1.1.1 ports 1089 > 102, data length 4, PA, DF, DSCP 0
4 11:15:16.687494 TCP out of range seq number * (#82) TCP: 10.1.1.14 > 10.1.1.1 ports 1089 > 102, data length 18, PA, DF, DSCP 0
5 11:15:16.688528 no matching TCP flow (#178) TCP: 10.1.1.14 > 10.1.1.1 ports 102 > 1089, A, DF, DSCP 0
6 11:15:16.688710 no matching TCP flow (#178) TCP: 10.1.1.14 > 10.1.1.1 ports 102 > 1089, data length 4, PA, DF, DSCP 0
7 11:15:16.690016 no matching TCP flow (#178) TCP: 10.1.1.14 > 10.1.1.1 ports 102 > 1089, data length 10, PA, DF, DSCP 0
```

Could anyone please suggest some idea to fix this issue?

Comment: I'm no expert, but it looks like your sending incomplete TCP streams. The OS is looking for the handshake in the TCP connection to track it but your sending just random data packets.

Comment: @theSmallNothing. Thanks for your comment. Just I want to send these random packets through my firewall. But its getting dropped with the above error messages. (I cant disable the firewall even) Please suggest some ideas to get the TCP handshake done for these packets.

Comment: Try using sendp rather than send, scapy docs say it works at layer 2, which is lower.

Comment: If I use sendp, packets are NOT reaching firewall itself.

Comment: When you say the firewall, do you mean inside the computer or an external one? Also how do you know packets are not reaching it? I missed the last part on your comment, you send a TCP handshake before opening a connection, google "scapy TCP handshake" for more info but be warned this is tricky. Also are the drops you see in the firewall logs important? In order to do a TCP replay, it would be easier if you could re-record the entire TCP conversation, including the TCP handshake.